# Pymongo cursor returns incomplete results

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have the two following scenarios using pymongo:

`cursor = db.col.find({'_id':{'$in':list_of_ids}})`

returns 87 records, while list_of_ids is 335 in length.

```
stuff = []
for item in list_of_ids:
        stuff.append(list(db.col.find({'_id':item})
```

returns all of the 335. I don't want to hit the db 335 times, but I also need to get all my records. I couldn't find anything in the documentation. The exhaust Cursor seems nice but I couldn't figure how to set it. The next() method just iterates one by one. The list(cursor) still returns the 87.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: How many times `for item in cursor:` runs?

Comment: Once; are you alluding to : `while True: try: for items in cursor... Except: break` ?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to the fact that there were duplicated _ids in the `list_of_ids`; while I do not have access to the code anymore, I bet if I did `set(list_of_ids)` it would have been 87.